# Shadow that appears as ball gets closer to ground

Tags: actionscript-3

I have developed a simple basketball game.  The ball can be thrown and bounces off the ground, walls, rim, and backboard.  I would like to have a ball shadow appear when the ball gets close to the ground.  I've done my research and am coming up with nothing.  So far I have had a limited amount of success with the following, running in the update loop of course:

```
shadow.alpha = _activeBall.y/600;
shadow.x = _activeBall.x;
```

600 is the floor, the maximum y value the ball can fall.  The code above gets me close, but the shadow is always present, even when I am high enough in the air that a shadow should not be seen.  I tried something like this:

```
if( _activeBall.y > 450 ) shadow.alpha = _activeBall.y/600;
shadow.x = _activeBall.x;
```

but that pops the shadow in to abruptly.  It would also be ideal if the scale of the shadow decreased as the ball moved away from the floor. I am stumped with the math with this one and was hoping someone here can recommend an approach for this.  Come on math gurus!  Whatcha got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you need to learn the skill of normalizing / rescaling.  It's not tough, as long as you know what you want.

It looks like you want `alpha` to be 0 when `_activeBall.y` < 450, then go from something less than 450/600 to eventually 600/600.  Since I don't know what you want your `alpha` to start at (0 or 0.25 seems logical), I'll just call it `alpha0`.  The good news for algebra - it lets you use a variable.  :-)

So, the first easy part:

```
if( _activeBall.y < 450 ) { shadow.alpha = 0; }
// I ALWAYS use {} in any control flow statement.
```

So, normalize the range you want - turn it into a number from 0 to 1.  Do this by subtracting the initial value and multiplying by the total range.

```
var normalized = (_activeBall.y - 450) / (600 - 450);
```

Note the `()`, otherwise you'd calculate `_activeBall.y - (450/150)`.

Now that you have the normalized value, apply it to your scale by doing the opposite function with your new scale - multiply it times the total range and add the initial value:

```
shadow.alpha = normalized * (1 - alpha0) + alpha0;
```

Incidentally, you can do similarly with the scale of the shadow, so that when it's higher up, it's smaller.  The normalized value will still be the same, and you can just set the `scaleX` and `scaleY` with that value.

Comment: Amazing!  Thanks so much!  I know this is a bit off topic but ever since I found out I could write functions sans curly brackets if there was only one execution in the function, I've done it as a means of saving line space.  Is there a particular reason you suggest I should not?

Comment: Also, in the last line of your suggested code I think you meant shadow.alpha = normalized * (1 - alpha0) + alpha0;  ??

Comment: Good catch. Yes, that last line should start with `shadow`; I've fixed it. As for the braces, I still did it all on one line, just with the security blanket of braces. For me, it helps accentuate the code that executes. Also, this habit removes the trap that everyone falls into at some point of just adding one line to debug with or otherwise, and having it not execute properly. It increases maintainability by removing that source for error. That's always more important to me than any saved space; whitespace and braces get removed by compilers, anyway.